# When is a process restarted in Erlang supervision?

Tags: erlang

Can you give some examples where a process gets restarted by Erlang supervisor. If a process dies, it will restart. But how does a process die?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take as example what occurs in the Erlang shell, for example consider the sequence:

```
1> self().
<0.32.0>
2> A = 1. 
1
3> self().
<0.32.0>
4> A = 2. 
** exception error: no match of right hand side value 2
5> self().
<0.37.0>
```

1> The first command asks to the shell to prompt its own Pid: `<0.32.0>`.

2> Next a new command set the variable A to 1, it works, since A was unbound.

3> A new request to the shell shows that its Pid didn't change.

4> trying to match A with the integer 2 fails, it raise an exception. In fact, in the background, the shell process dies, and a supervisor restart it immediately.

5> It can be verified with a new request to get the shell Pid, now it is `<0.37.0>`.

6> when the shell died, it has lost every information, and it is restarted from scratch. But during initialization it can connect to some other processes who was in charge of keeping the history of the session, and all the bound variables. It can be verified by asking the value of A:

```
6> A.
1
```

7> or by asking the history

```
7> h().
1: self()
-> <0.32.0>
2: A = 1
-> 1
3: self()
-> <0.32.0>
4: A = 2
-> {'EXIT',{{badmatch,2},[{erl_eval,expr,3,[]}]}}
5: self()
-> <0.37.0>
6: A
```

Depending on the environment (hardware failure, loss of communication, bad parameters, bug...) an erlang process may die with an Error reason. If it is managed in a supervision tree (or your own monitoring) it can be restarted from scratch. It is the application responsibility to provide the means to all the processes to recover the appropriate state.

An erlang process may also die with the reason "normal", for example when a user close a session (in the shell you type q().), in this case, the supervisor will not restart it.

You will find many valuable information on the web:

[design principle](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html)

[erlang.org supervisor](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html)

[learn you some erlang : run time errors](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions#run-time-errors)

[learn you some erlang : errors and processes](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-processes)

[learn you some erlang : supervisors](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/supervisors)